# How to find two same text nodes

Tags: jquery

I have a table with data in in. For simplicity lets say it has only one column and no header. I want JQuery to iterate over all rows to see if the text in any of the cells in the same column is repeated in another row. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
<tr><td>one</td></tr>
<tr><td>two</td></tr>
<tr><td>three</td></tr>
<tr><td>four</td></tr>
<tr><td>five</td></tr>
<tr><td>one</td></tr>   <!--It is doubled-->
<tr><td>six</td></tr>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something client-side with javascript - what has this got to do with MySQL or indeed PHP for that matter?  Please use relevant tags.

Comment: Wrong tag sorry, I haven't noticed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
var contents = new Array();
$("td").each(function(idx) {
    var value = $(this).html();
    if($.inArray(value, contents) == -1) {
        contents.push(value);
    } else {
        console.log("Row '" + idx + "' : duplicate value '" + value +"'");
    }
});
```

This will take each of your row one by one and retrieve the value, check in previous values (stored in an array) if the value already exists, if not it adds it to the array else it displays a message in the console.

Instead of `console.log()` you can do what you need, store it somewhere, change the class, etc.

Comment: It's so simple and yet I didn't come up with this. Glad I asked.  Just one error there: line `var contents = new Array();` should be inside the function otherwise the function called again will always show duplicate

Comment: No, putting this line in the function will never show duplicate as it will override the value with a new array everytime. If you want to call this multiple times, wrap it in a function and call the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nodeArr = [];
$('tr td').each(function () {
    var textStr = $(this).text();
    if (typeof nodeArr[textStr] === 'undefined') {  
        nodeArr[textStr] = $(this);
    } else { // we have a duplicate
        var el1 = nodeArr[textStr],
            el2 = $(this);
        // and do something with them!
    }        
});
```